# Kotlin longest zigzag path in binary tree

Tags: kotlin, recursion

I'm attempting to answer longest zigzag path in a binary tree on leetcode with recursion in kotlin. The input looks like this

```
[1,null,1,1,1,null,null,1,1,null,1,null,null,null,1,null,1]
```

and represents a binary tree. The problem I'm having is related to the recursion, the current code I have returns 1 after visiting all nodes in the tree. But I intended for the code to add 1 after each tree node is hit and add it to that zigzags total count.

```
left += traverseDirection(root?.left, "left")
right += traverseDirection(root?.right, "right")
```

left and right just represent the corresponding zigzag for each path side. What I want to know is how to add to these values after each recursive call in the way my println statements are doing it

```
/**
 * Example:
 * var ti = TreeNode(5)
 * var v = ti.`val`
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * class TreeNode(var `val`: Int) {
 *     var left: TreeNode? = null
 *     var right: TreeNode? = null
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    fun longestZigZag(root: TreeNode?): Int {
        var left: Int = 0
        var right: Int = 0
        
        left += traverseDirection(root?.left, "left")
        right += traverseDirection(root?.right, "right")
    
        return maxOf(left, right)
    }
    fun traverseDirection(root: TreeNode?, direction: String): Int {
        if (direction == "left" && root?.left == null){
           return 0
        }
        
        if (direction == "right" && root?.right == null){
           return 0
        }
        
        var current = root
        
        if (direction == "left"){
            current = root?.left
            traverseDirection(current, "right")
            println("add 1")
            return 1 
        }
        
        if (direction == "right"){
            current = root?.right
            traverseDirection(current, "left")
            println("add 1")
            return 1
        }
        
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the recursive call, if you're ignoring its return value?

Answer (score 0):

I can't easily run your code to verify this, but I believe you need to replace this:

```kotlin
traverseDirection(current, "right")
return 1
```

With this:

```kotlin
return traverseDirection(current, "right") + 1
```

And the same with the "left" line.

Also, I think your solution will find the longest zigzag only if it starts at the root. You would have to run `longestZigZag()` for each node in the tree and find the maximum. That would give you a naive solution with O(n²) complexity.